# What are my options for a processor to fulfill the requirement of a video signal processing application?

Tags: arm, embedded, imageprocessing

I 'm a collage student and I 'm designing an embedded system of a smart camera for traffic surveillance as my graduation bachelor project. The camera does the following:

- Monitors a traffic lane with a specific speed limit.
- If a violation of the speed limit is successfully detected a sub image of the car is captured.
- the captured image is transmitted through a network interface to an android device which hosts a UI of my design to view this car image.

specifications of the system:

- The system will be directly connected to an image sensor (CMOS sensor seemed quite promising in my search results but it is open for suggestions.
- Resolution and frame rate depends on what does it take to capture an average quality image for a moving vehicle (LM-9618 CMOS sensor provides 640x480 and 30 fps max, also open for suggestions).

Preferences for the processor:

- Reasonable power consumption as it will be tested on a traffic lane.
- Reasonable budget for a student as I do not intend to go fancy about it.
- Programming software is preferred to be java or C languages based.

I found out about ARM providing boards based on their processors for students applications but I couldn't decide which one is suitable for my application so I would appreciate any kind of guidance concerning the ARM board or the processor itself. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Literally: hundreds if not thousands of options.

Comment: Even if this question was on topic, I wouldn't help big brother.

Comment: @EugeneSh. just anything that comes in mind :)

Comment: Go to a major micros manufacturer website, and use their selection matrix by application.

Comment: Don't start by going shopping, get your software working on a PC (or possibly a smartphone) and then pick something appropriate to the computational load.  If you run out of time, you can always get a smaller PC in a hurry, but spending all your time learning to do video on an embedded board that might not be suitable rather than dealing with the key image processing task means you'll have little to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like an ambitious graduate project. You need to scale it down a lot to make it achievable. Do that by buying in the hardware complete, ie don't try to develop your own hardware. I would start by looking at the Raspberry Pi 2 as a processor module. It has 1GB of RAM and a 900MHz quad core processor which should give you enough power to process video. You can get a Raspberry Pi camera which will give up to 1080P resolution and has a simple interface to the processor. Also, there is excellent community support for the Rasp Pi, with lots of examples for handling video using the video libraries that Rasp Pi make available. I cannot remember seeing a library to calculate the speed of a moving image, but there is a good chance that something like that has been developed by someone. Best of all you should be able to buy the Rasp Pi and camera for around $50.